# How set a UIView subview larger then its parent superview in IB?

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, subview

Can someone please reveal the secret handshake in IB to allow a UIView subview to exceed the bounds of its parent superview?

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 5):

Make the subview bigger than it's parent view and set the **clip subviews** of the parent view to NO.

(Note that the part of the subview that is not inside it's parent view will not be clickable even though it's visible)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it large than the superview, but it won't be visible out of bounds (at least not in my experimenting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first find the parent view controller, then use parent view controller to present subview.